# Pikadate datepicker: How can I get the dates into the divs?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to use divs instead of input-fields for Pikadate datepicker, and it kinda works, except that I don't know how to get the dates into the divs.

Html:

```
<div id="start"></div>
<div id="end"></div>
```

Javascript:

```
var picker = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('start'),
    minDate: new Date(),
    onSelect: function() {
        picker2.setMinDate(new Date(this.getDate().getTime()+parseInt(24*60*60*1000)));
        if(Number(new Date(this.getDate()))>Number(new Date(document.getElementById('end').value)))
        {
            document.getElementById('end').value="";
        }
    }
});
var picker2 = new Pikaday({
    field: document.getElementById('end'),
});
```

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/e1hrxd19/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the onSelect function add

```
document.getElementById('start').innerHTML=picker.getDate().toDateString();
```

Or something like that. The important part is the getDate() function on picker

Here's an updated fiddle for the start div: http://jsfiddle.net/e1hrxd19/3/